# Remove the space between each paragraphs in Latex

Tags: latex

The template I am using in Latex is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} %Margins
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr }
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1ex}{0ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{1ex}{0ex}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1ex}{0ex}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\include{thesis.preamble}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=2cm,right=2cm} %Only for the title new margins

%Title parameters
\title{Title}
\author{Student's name}
\submitdate{July 2017}
\supervisor{supervisor's name}
\cosupervisor{co-supervisor's name}

\maketitle

\maketitle
\restoregeometry

\preface
\cleardoublepage 
\input{dedication/dedication}
\input{acknowledgements/acknowledgements}
\input{abstract/abstract}

\body

%Introduction of the project
\input{introduction/introduction}
\input{methods/methods}
\input{results/results}
\input{discussion/discussion}

\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables

% appendices come here
\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\input{appendix/appendix}

\end{document}
```

I have also following code in the Latex

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\input{Styles/mathchars.sty}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}

\input{Styles/blocked.sty}
\input{Styles/uhead.sty}
\input{Styles/boxit.sty}
\input{Styles/icthesis.sty}

\newcommand{\titlelinespacing}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0} \normalsize}
\newcommand{\normallinespacing}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} \normalsize}
\newcommand{\mediumlinespacing}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} \normalsize}
\newcommand{\narrowlinespacing}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0} \normalsize}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\cftsetindents{section}{0in}{0.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0in}{0.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0in}{0.5in}
```

When I make a new paragraph, a space is generated between each paragraphs like the following image:
[image]

for the above image I have the following code :

```
\normallinespacing

\chapter{Introduction}

The aim of this thesis work is to understand how High-Pressure Supersonic Turbines react to the unsteady and unstationary flow conditions when they operate with Rotating Detonation Engines. 

In recent years this problem has been investigated by several authors. Sun and et al[1] has investigated the effects of the diverging nozzle downstream of Rotating Detonation Engines. They have found out that the integrating diverging nozzle to Rotating Detonation Engines reduces the total pressure and temperature load downstream of Rotating Detonation Engines. Liu and Panigua[2] has also tried to intregrate this type of combustor with turbines by changing endwall shape of the first stage of the turbines. A modified endwall design has prevented the unstarting of the stator passage and enabled significant gain in performance. Paniagua and et al[3] has investigated also bladeless turbine configuration for the supersonic inlet flow. This has been done through a wavy hub surface which enables shocks and expansion fans and generates torque. Sousa[4] has also studied the designing of Supersonic Turbine according to the flow conditions downstream of Rotating Detonation Engine.

This master thesis work has the motivation to design a suitable supersonic turbine  to be integrated with pressure gain combustors.
\section{Motivation}

\section{Objectives}
\section{Structure of the Report}


\newpage
```

I want to remove the space between each paragraphs. Do you know how to remove the space between paragraphs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make a [mre] which allows us to reproduce the problem without having aces to all your files?

Comment: By default, latex does not add any space between paragraphs. Do you maybe have the `parskip` hidden somewhere in the files you don't show us?

Comment: off-topic: you might want to adjust your bib style to add the missing spaces ....

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/project/61f1e005a01b2673070af669 the file I am using is accessible via this link.

Comment: Add the code to your question. The page you link to just says "Restricted, sorry you don’t have permission to load this page."

Comment: I added the codes.

Comment: Sorry, but we still can't compile the code fragments. You include a number of file, we don't have. The code you show does not add spaces between paragraphs

Answer (score 1):

Add the command

```tex
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} % additional skip between paragraphs
```

in the preamble, and the problem should be solved.

> By the way, you may get the answer faster on [TEX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).